# Sort by iso string descending isn't working

Tags: javascript, isodate

**Desired Behaviour**

Sort array of objects by object's `iso_string` property, descending.

**Actual Behaviour**

Array order is not changed.

**What I've Tried**

I must have made a simple error somewhere because multiple posts confirm that is the correct `sort()` syntax to use.

`iso_string` value is generated with `new Date().toISOString()`;

```js
var dates = [{
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:02pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:02:22.485Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:12pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:12:04.471Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:05pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:05:45.818Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:00pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:00:46.954Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 03:56pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T05:56:13.968Z"
}];

var sorted_dates = dates.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.iso_string - a.iso_string;
});

console.log(sorted_dates);
```

**Edit:**  I wrapped values in `new Date()` and it sorts correctly.

Comment: Can you subtract two strings in JavaScript? What is the expected result from doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iso_string` is in string type you need to convert it into date and then sort. Here is a improved sample

```js
var dates = [{
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:02pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:02:22.485Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:12pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:12:04.471Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:05pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:05:45.818Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:00pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:00:46.954Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 03:56pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T05:56:13.968Z"
}];
var sorted_dates = dates.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(b.iso_string) - new Date(a.iso_string);
});
console.log(sorted_dates);
```

You can also use [localCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) without converting the string into date.

```js
var dates = [{
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:02pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:02:22.485Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:12pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:12:04.471Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:05pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:05:45.818Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:00pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:00:46.954Z"
}, {
  "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 03:56pm",
  "iso_string": "2018-09-22T05:56:13.968Z"
}];

var sorted_dates = dates.sort((a, b)=>b.iso_string.localeCompare(a.iso_string));
console.log(sorted_dates);
```

Comment: The OP doesn't "need to convert to date", string comparison using *localeCompare* works fine.

Comment: @RobG I wasn't aware of that function but thank you I checked and updated with one more solution

Answer (score 10):

Since you have [`ISO 8601`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date which can be sorted lexicographically, you can use [`string.localCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort it.

```js
var dates = [{ "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:02pm", "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:02:22.485Z" }, { "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:12pm", "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:12:04.471Z" }, { "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:05pm", "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:05:45.818Z"}, { "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 04:00pm", "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:00:46.954Z" }, { "formatted_date": "22/09/2018 @ 03:56pm", "iso_string": "2018-09-22T05:56:13.968Z" }],
    sorted_dates = dates.sort((a, b) => b.iso_string.localeCompare(a.iso_string));

console.log(sorted_dates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```